# "ГотовО" или "готовЫ"?

Tags: согласование, числительные

*К началу сезона готово 894 котельных.* Или "готовы"?

Answer (score 3):

Перед вами проблема согласования сказуемого с числительными. Хотя форма сказуемого не регламентируется жестко, существует ряд факторов, способствующих употреблению формы единственного или множественного числа.

На постановку сказуемого в форму единственного числа влияет стремление автора текста обратить внимание читателей на пассивность подлежащего, совместность действия действующих лиц, а также на количество, названное в подлежащем. Пассивность подлежащего может подчеркиваться употреблением в качестве сказуемых глаголов со значением бытия, наличия: быть существовать, иметься и др.
(см. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo)

Исходя из этого, для вашего предложения больше подходит форма единственного числа: К началу сезона **готово** 894 котельных.

Answer (score 0):

Не будет ошибкой ни тот, ни другой вариант.