# Как правильно писать?

Tags: согласование, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Как правильно пишется: *судьей рассмотрен**о** 82 дела* или *рассмотрен**ы** 82 дела?*

Answer (score 4):

Грамматически возможны оба варианта, но выбор зависит от контекста и требуемого значения: количество важнее или индивидуальные особенности дел. Вне контекста большим числам свойственно согласование с числительным ("рассмотрен**о**").

> Судьёй рассмотрено 82 дела (из 102 переданных в суд).
>
> Судьёй рассмотрены все 82 дела, порученные ему лично президентом.
>
> Судьёй рассмотрены следующие 82 дела: [список].
>
> Судьёй рассмотрены 3 дела, недавно широко обсуждавшиеся в прессе.
>
> Всего судьёй вчера рассмотрено 3 дела.

Answer (score 0):

Подобные вопросы не раз задавались. Вот [один из них](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428300/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B/428303#comment431881_428303.). Вот [еще один](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427583/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%9E-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%AB/427586#427586).
Правила изложены [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo).