# О единицах времени: "прошли" или "прошло"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, числительные

*С момента публикации новости прошло (прошли) 9283 секунды.*

С одной стороны, "3 секунды прошли", но с другой — с большими числами почему-то лучше (по-моему) звучит "прошло". Говоря о годах, мы обычно используем слово "прошло", кроме случаев, когда хотим подчеркнуть, как долго тянулся каждый год. Применимо ли то же самое к часам, минутам и секундам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В реалистичном контексте с такой цифрой речь может идти о времени и его количестве, с акцентом на подразумеваемом "*количестве*" - с ним по роду и числу согласуется глагол:

> С момента публикации новости **прошло** [*количество времени,
>   в секундах выражаемое так:)*] 9283 секунды (времени).

Но при специфическом *акценте на секундах* (которые напр. ранее упоминались как таковые) возможно согласование с "секундами":

> Суд обязал данный сайт разместить опровержение не позже, чем через
>   9283 секунды с момента публикации. Эти [*какие? - те самые, которых было заявлено столько-то*] 9283 секунды давно **прошли**.

*Количество* секунд влияет на данный выбор не само по себе, а через общий контекст:

> Три секунды [каждая - на счету], отведённые на подготовку к выстрелу, уже прошл**и**.
>
> Прошл**о** аж три секунды [это много времени], прежде чем он отреагировал.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае я бы посоветовал поставить сказуемое в единственном числе:

**С момента публикации новости прошло 9283 секунды.**

Выбор единственного числа в данном случае обоснован пассивностью подлежащего, а также желанием обратить внимание на количество, названное в подлежащем.

А вообще-то выбор числа сказуемого - задача непростая. Подобные вопросы не раз задавались. Вот некоторые ссылки:

[Как правильно писать?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428540/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c/428551#428551)

[Защищено / защищены](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428300/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B/428303#comment431881_428303).

["ГотовО" или "готовЫ"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427583/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%9E-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%AB/427586#427586)

А правила изложены [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo)